# Crawl : Error from SharePoint site: *-*

Tags: crawl

I can't index a Webapp since few days. I have this error :

> The object was not found. ( Error from SharePoint site: *-* URL:
>   `http://Sh-spwfe01/` Reason: The request failed with HTTP status 404:
>   Not Found. Error 2147750401. ; SearchID =
>   5E99990B-4A19-4FF5-943F-7C17F54D2311 )
>   security initialization failed, hr = 80041205 error Message Error from SharePoint site: *-*

I don't know how to find the origin of this error

Comment: https://sh.xxxxxx.com
Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled. ( Error from SharePoint site: *-* URL: http://sh-spwfe01/ Reason: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden. Error 2147750405. , CorrelationID: e304459d-fe01-e025-d785-ee7d4b02cde2; SearchID = E72AF19E-A486-4FF9-B4F1-CD5647BF5311 )

Answer (score 0):

Solved : Invalid reference in the SiteDataServers property !
I don't know how and when this property has been modified.